# How to disable ssh-agent forwarding

Tags: linux, ssh

ssh-agent forwarding can be accomplished with `ssh -A ...`.

Most references I have found state that the local machine must configure `~/.ssh/config` to enable AgentForwarding with the following code:

```
Host <trusted_ip>
  ForwardAgent yes

Host *
  ForwardAgent no
```

However, with this configuration, I am still able to see my local machines keys when tunneling into a remote machine, with `ssh -A user@remote_not_trusted_ip`, and running `ssh-add -l`.

From the configuration presented above, I would expect that the ssh-agent forwarding would fail and the keys of the local machine would not be listed by `ssh-add -l`.

Why is the machine `@remote_not_trusted_ip` able to access the ssh-agent forwarded keys even though the `~/.ssh/config` file states the following?

```
Host *
  ForwardAgent no
```

How can i prevent ssh-agent from forwarding keys to machines not explicitly defined in the `~/.ssh/config`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How can i prevent ssh-agent from forwarding keys to machines not explicitly defined in the `~/.ssh/config`?

It is the default behavior. If you do not allow it in `~/.ssh/config` it will not be forwarded. But the command-line arguments have higher priority so it overwrites what is defined in the configuration,as explained in the manual page for `ssh_config`:

> `ssh(1)` obtains configuration data from the following sources in the following order:
>
> 1. command-line options
> 2. user's configuration file (~/.ssh/config)
> 3. system-wide configuration file (/etc/ssh/ssh_config)

So as already said, you just need to provide correct arguments to `ssh`.

## So back to the questions:

> Why is the machine @remote_not_trusted_ip able to access the ssh-agent forwarded keys even though the ~/.ssh/config file states the following?
>
> ```
> Host *
>   ForwardAgent no
> ```

Because the command-line argument `-A` has higher priority than the configuration files.

> How can I prevent ssh-agent from forwarding keys to machines not explicitly defined in the `~/.ssh/config`?

Do not use `-A` command-line option if you do not want forward your `ssh-agent`. Use `-a` command-line option instead.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky thank you for your feedback. This answer was an addition to the other one and it was explaining "why is that happening", instead of only "how to fix it". I added the explicit answers the the OP questions. I hope that now the answer is more understandable.

Comment: Excellent. Vote changed.

Answer (score 7):

You are using -A option to connect. man ssh says :

> -A      Enables forwarding of the authentication agent connection.

You should connect without -A, just using :

```
ssh user@remote_not_trusted_ip
```

CLI args will have priority on ssh config file.

By the way, if you want to connect to your trusted ip without forwarding, you can also use :

```
ssh -a user@trusted_ip
```

> -a      Disables forwarding of the authentication agent connection.

Answer (score 6):

This is over a year old, but I encountered the same issue and landed on a config option that works.

I had a problem when I connected from my home computer to my work computer that Git commands no longer worked. I figured out that it was because the connecting home computer's public key was forwarded, which was not configured for that GitHub account.

The `-a` command line options fixed the problem by not forwarding the authentication agent connection. I also thought that the equivalent `~/.ssh/config` option would be this:

```
ForwardAgent no
```

When that didn't work I looked for other configuration variables, and finally found that this one worked.

```
IdentityAgent none
```

Answer (score 1):

This part of the man-page is crucial:

> Since the first obtained value for each parameter is used, more
> host-specific declarations should be given near the beginning of the
> file, and general defaults at the end.

Put your Host * with ForwardAgent yes at the end and the specific Host with ForwardAgent, not at the start of the .ssh/config

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to the question, and maybe just semantics:

Why is the machine @remote_not_trusted_ip able to access the ssh-agent **forwarded keys** even though the ~/.ssh/config file states the following?

My understanding is that authentication keys are never "forwarded" to a remote computer. Rather ssh-agent forwards authentication challenges from a remote server back to the computer that holds the authentication private key through whatever chain of remote computers the ssh connection is running through.